# richfaces 4 a4j:commandButton navigation fails on internet explorer

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I´m using this libraries:

1. JSF 2.0.8 (MyFaces)
2. Richfaces 4.5.7

I have this code for testing navigation with `<a4j:commandButton>` component:

```
<f:view>

    <h:form id="form_citas_uno">

        <h:panelGrid id="pnlBtnes">
            <a4j:commandButton id="cb_agendar_id" value=" "
                styleClass="btnNuevoAgendamiento"
                action="irAgendarCita" >
            </a4j:commandButton>    
            <a4j:commandButton id="cb_agendar_id2" value=" "
                styleClass="btnNuevoAgendamiento"
                action="irAgendarCitaAfiliado" >
            </a4j:commandButton>
        </h:panelGrid>  

    </h:form>

</f:view>
```

The navigation rule for outcome `irAgendarCita` is: (works on Firefox and Chrome)

```
<navigation-case>
    <from-outcome>irAgendarCita</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/jspx/agendamiento/externo/datosCita.jspx</to-view-id>                               
</navigation-case>
```

The navigation rule for outcome `irAgendarCitaAfiliado` is: (works on all browser)

```
<navigation-case>
    <from-outcome>irAgendarCitaAfiliado</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/jspx/agendamiento/afiliado/datosCitaAfiliado.jspx</to-view-id> 
    <redirect/>          
</navigation-case>
```

Only `<redirect/>` difference

The navigation works on both rules for Firefox and Chrome, but for Internet Explorer the first one (irAgendarCita) throws a error:

```
SCRIPT5007: Object expected
File: jsf.js.jspx, Line: 6631, Column: 13
```

Is this a normal behaviour?

I will have to change all my a4j:commandButtons to execute navigations?

I will have to change all my navigation rules?

**NOTE:** I´m migrating from jsf 1.2 and this a4j:commandButtons was worked fine in previous versions.

Comment: Looks like an issue with MyFaces, you can try upgrading to a newer version. Or you can try using just h:commandButton, given that you're not using the buttons for partial updates. What is the code around line 6631?

Comment: What in that blog post says you can't upgrade?

Comment: @Makhiel Unfortunately it is not an option to upgrade myfaces because we use IBM Was 8.5 (I will update my question), but I guess I can use [this](http://planet.jboss.org/post/re_routing_jsf_resource_requests_with_richfaces_resource_mapping) approach to replace the file jsf.js. Line 6631 is throw Exception

Comment: The IBM implementation of myfaces is personalized, I think that I have to wait to official upgrade from IBM. This is a production enviroment shared with other apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this comment on [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_commandButton.html) of 3.3.X version of richfaces

> Common JSF navigation could be performed after an Ajax submit and
>   partial rendering, but Navigation Case must be defined as `<redirect/>`
>   in order to avoid problems with some browsers.

I assumed this problem persist for version 4.

I'm replacing that buttons for `<h:commandButton>` when I need forward navigation